# How do I select data only from one table using outer apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to select the data present only in table A excluding the data present in table B. Left join is taking a lot of time, so, thinking of doing it with outer apply instead of left join. But I am not getting the desired output. Why is the NULL condition not working inside outer apply? And the two tables have at least a million records in each and table A is joined with a large table before arriving to this point. Note: unlike in example below, table A has many columns (id, name, city, dob) and table B has two columns.

Table A

```
id name
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
```

Table B

```
id name
3 c
4 d
```

Expected result

```
id name
1 a
2 b
5 e
6 f
```

Partial code:

> ```
> select from #t1  
> DECLARE @t1 TABLE (id int, name varchar(10))  
> INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 3,'c'  INSERT INTO @t1 select 4,'d' 
> select #t1.* from #t1  
> OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM @t1 WHERE #t1.id =
>  [@t1].id  AND [@t1].id IS NULL)t
> ```

Comment: "For some reason" - so explain yourself and your logic. This should not be a guessing game, OUTER APPLY will not filter rows. You could use EXCEPT. You could use NOT EXISTS. You could OUTER JOIN. But your sample query seems to be completely unrelated to your "desired results".

Comment: Outer apply is pretty expensive, I think. Not exists is your best bet.

Comment: Madhukar, do you try query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `operator EXCEPT`.It returns all distinct records from the first dataset (A) and remove from that result the records that are returned from the second dataset (B).

```
SELECT id,name FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT id,name FROM B
```

If there's different column's count for each table, you can try NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.id=A.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with NOT IN as below. Indexing on Column ID in both table will make things more faster.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A 
WHERE Table_A.id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table_B)
```